# cant echo a variable recieved from a POST request

Tags: php, sql

I've encountered a weird problem. 
I have the following code (sample, got many variables) :

```
$NumOfBulbs = $_POST['NumOfBulbs'];
```

Later I have an SQL query :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO poles (NumOfBulbs) VALUES (?)";
```

And a bind_param call :

```
$stmt = $connectStmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $NumOfBulbs);
$stmt->execute();
```

The query works fine and updates the database, but whenever I try to print the variable, I get null.
I need that number so I can do a for loop later on, so I wanted to loop like that :

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $NumOfBulbs ; $i++ ) {}
```

But the value `$NumOfBulbs` is null.
So.. where did it go ? Why it exists in the bind_param and sends the data correctly to the db ?

Comment: can you add complete code ??

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST['NumOfBulbs'])` say ?

Comment: At start assign same value into another variable and check that